# Cannot get stripeToken in Developing of Stripe Elements

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm CEO and Developer at robal, Inc. This is the Japanese Startup Company.

I'm developing C to C(Consumer to Consumer) web application service and will add [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) as the online payment system.

My developing environment is following:
PHP 7.1
Laravel 5.5

I'm developing using the Stripe Elements document.
[Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart)

I want to ask a question.

I have completed all the steps of this document.

After entering credit card information in the payment form and submitting form, stripeToken should be issued, but in my implementation stripeToken is not issued.

Debugging the JavaScript copied and pasted from the Stripe document apparently seems that the following points are not running properly.

**JavaScript**

```
// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error.
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
            // Send the token to your server.
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
    });
});
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}
```

I think that the code above ignites when submitting the payment form and that stripeToken is issued, but it seems that this is not igniting well.

However, I do not know why this is not ignited even if I submit it.
If anyone knows the solution or something at all, I would like you to tell me.

I will paste the code that actually has the problem in the following.

**reserve.blade.php**

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form action="{{ route('experiences.complete', $model) }}" method="post" id="payment-form">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-row">

                    <label for="card-element">お支払い</label>

                    <div id="card-element">
                      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

                </div>

              <button class="btn btn-primary">支払う</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
(function(){
    // Create a Stripe client.
    var stripe = Stripe('{{ config('services.stripe.key')}}');

    // Create an instance of Elements.
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '18px',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        style: style,
        hidePostalCode: true,
        });

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element');

    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });

    // Handle form submission.
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the user if there was an error.
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
          // Send the token to your server.
          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
      });
    });
    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }
})();
```

Comment: You've set the public key in `config('services.stripe.key')` properly? You're not sending a live key to the test api or vice versa? Do you see any errors in the web inspector's console? Do you see a network request being sent and a response received?

Comment: Yes, I've set the public key properly. Although I set directly public key, did not work. In console, errord only other js error. Maybe I think this is not problem.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to submit the form? Does a network request go out with your form data? Is a response received?

Comment: No. I am watching it at the console, but nothing happens. Even if I submit form, 
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
It has not occurred.